# Row Level Security in SQL Server 2016 Express?

Tags: sql-server, wonderware

I'm working with a third party application (Wonderware Historian) and trying to implement row-level-security. The database is hosted on SQL Server 2016 Express, does anyone know if RLS is available in the express editions? I've looked all over and can't find a definitive answer.

This is what I get, intuition says express doesn't support this but I'd like to be sure before we explore upgrading to SQL Server 2016 (standard).

```
CREATE SECURITY POLICY testPolicy
...
Msg 534, Level 15, State 4, Line 1
'CREATE SECURITY POLICY' failed because it is not supported in the edition of this SQL Server instance '...'. See books online for more details on feature support in different SQL Server editions.
```

Comment: It is available from 2016 Express starting with SP1, which made a lot of features less dependent on edition. If your able to patch up to SP1 you should be able to make it work.

Comment: It does but you can't use 2016 RTM. Always use the latest service pack. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56840

Comment: Downloading the latest SP2 now, I thought we were all patched up but apparently not. I'll update my answer later if the issue is resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

TZHX was correct, I was missing SP1. Patched up to SP2 and I'm able to create security policies on SQL Server 2016 Express.